# How do I convert an infix expression to a postfix expression?

Tags: c, infix-notation

I am trying to write a `C` program to convert infix expressions to postfix and calculate with entered values. When I enter (2+14)*5 I get (2 14) 5 * + but it should be 2 14 + 5 *. So my questions:

1. Where did I go wrong?
2. How can change code to delete parentheses at the last form (postfix)?

Thanks for any help.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<math.h>

#define oper(x) (x=='+' || x=='-' || x=='*' || x=='/')

char in[30], post[30], stack[30];
int top=-1;

void push(char x)
{
    stack[++top]=x;
}

char pop()
{
    return stack[top--];
}

int precedence(char c)
{
    if (c=='+' || c=='-')
        return 1;
    if (c=='*' || c=='/')
        return 2;
    if (c=='(')
        return 3;
}

main()
{
    char c;
    int l,i,j=0,st1[20],k,h,f,eval,s,N;
    printf("Enter the infix expression : ");
    scanf("%s",&in);
    l=strlen(in);
    for(i=0;i<=l;i++)
    {
        if(oper(in[i]))
        {
            post[j++]=' ';
            while(precedence(in[i])<precedence(stack[top]))
            {
                post[j++]=stack[top];
                pop();
                post[j++]=' ';

            }
            push(in[i]);
        }
        else if(in[i]=='\0')
        {
            while(top!=-1)
            {
                post[j++]=' ';
                post[j++]=stack[top];
                pop();
            }
        }
        else
            post[j++]=in[i];
    }
    post[j]='\0';
    printf("Postfix Expression : %s\n",post);
    i=0;top=-1;f=0;k=0;
    while(i<j)
    {
        if(oper(post[i]))
        {
            f=1;
            c=post[i];
            eval=0;
            switch(c)
            {
                case '+':
                    eval=st1[top-1]+st1[top];
                    break; 
                case '-':
                    eval=st1[top-1]-st1[top];
                    break;
                case '*':
                    eval=st1[top-1]*st1[top];
                    break;
                case '/':
                    eval=st1[top-1]/st1[top];
                    break;
            }
            top--;
            st1[top]=eval; 
        }
        else if(post[i]==' ')
        {
            if(f==0)
            {
                h=i-k;
                s=0;
                while(post[h]!=' ')
                {
                    N=(int)post[h];
                    N=N-48;
                    s=s+N*(pow(10,(k-1)));
                    k--;
                    h++;
                }
                st1[++top]=s;
            }
            k=0;
        }
        else 
        {
            k++;
            f=0;
        }
        i++; 
    }
    printf("Value : %d\n",st1[top]);
}
```

Comment: RPN is harder to do than a simple recursive descent approach. Are you obliged to use Polish notation?

Comment: :D ofcourse ı know it s more difficlt but it is a subject of Data Structure lesson what can i do?

Comment: Please don't use scanf. fgets is the recommended way to read stdin. Implicit return type from main is also considered bad style.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't looked in too much detail at your code, but you don't seem to be handling parentheses in the input in any special way; they have a very specific meaning WRT order of operations.

My guess is that your program is treating parens just like digits, and is parsing the input as (substituing L and R for left-paren and right-paren, respectively) L2 + (14R * 5), in which case the output is correct.

Comment: +1 This appears to be trying to mimic a simplified shift-reduce parser, and i find it odd that ')' is nowhere in the precedence lookup.

Answer (score -1):

In the function `precedence`, you should try

```
if((c=='(') || (c==')')) {
  return 3;
}
```